# Is system drive involved when transferring files between external sources?

Tags: hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive, file-transfer

I often transfer files from my external HDD to my USB flash drive. Sometimes I use my computer which has the OS in the SSD and sometimes the other computer with the OS in HDD.

Are these file transfers from external sources (ext. HDD to USB flash) affected by the hard drives that host the operating system, for example by means of caching them in the host drive before transferring, thus affecting the transfer speed? Or is the path of the transfer is as follows?

> source - SATA - south-bridge chip - SATA - destination

Comment: Unless you are transfering so much data that it cannot fit into the virtual mmemory and has to be written to the systems cache then the internal system drive would have no data written to it.

Comment: It depends on many factors.